# Java - Chat async

Tags: java, socket, async, chat

Estou querendo implementar um chat em java, que funcione de forma assíncrona, e queria saber qual a melhor arquitetura para fazer isso.

Consegui fazer um chat público utilizando sockets(Netty), porém cheguei ao seguinte problema:

1. O servidor envia as mensagens pra todo mundo, ao invés de um grupo específico. (Como selecionar o destinatário?)

Se tiver algum projeto de exemplo, agradeço.

Comment: A tua pergunta está extremamente genérica, fica difícil responder com pouco informação. Tu tem usado algum protocolo específico pra comunicar com os clientes? Com sockets TCP e UDP é bem trivial definir um endereço destino.

Comment: @Roney Estou usando [Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat), mas não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer comunicação entre clientes. Por isso quero saber qual melhor arquitetura pra fazer chat.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço o Netty, mas pelo link que você passou, acredito que ele esteja mandando as mensagens para todo mundo neste método:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
// Send the received message to all channels but the current one.

    for (Channel c: channels) {
        if (c != ctx.channel()) {
            c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] " + msg + '\n');
            } else {
                c.writeAndFlush("[you] " + msg + '\n');
            }
        }
}
```

E, pelo visto, cada `Channel` representa um usuário conectado ao servidor. Se você escolher apenas um deles, só esse cliente receberá a mensagem.

De qualquer modo, acredito que o Netty ofereça uma série de recursos que você não deva precisar no momento. Eu começaria dando uma olhada nos [tutoriais do java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). Lá tem um exemplo pronto de [servidor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java) e [cliente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java).

Apesar de serem muito simples, com algumas modificações, é possível transformá-los num programa de chat completo, com mensagens separadas para cada usuário.

Aqui vai uma experiência minha, baseada no tutorial do javadocs.

Eu incluí um `ArrayList<>` para guardar os usuários que se conectam:

```
public static ArrayList<SCThread> lista = new ArrayList<SCThread>();
```

E, quando o servidor recebe uma mensagem, eu faço um loop como o do Netty, mas dessa vez procurando pelo destinatário da mensagem.

Exemplo do servidor:

[image: ServidorChat]

Exemplo de clientes (na minha versão, `x <msg>` envia mensagem para todos):

[image: ClienteChat0]

Já `<número> <msg>` envia a mensagem para o usuário com este número:

[image: ClienteChat1]
[image: ClienteChat2]

ServidorChat.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServidorChat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Utilizacao: java ServidorChat <porta>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("ServidorChat");
        int porta = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        boolean portaAberta = true;

        try (ServerSocket servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(porta)) {
            while (portaAberta) {
                SCThread s = new SCThread(servidorSocket.accept());
                s.start();
                Usuarios.adicionar(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro ao abrir a porta " + porta);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

SCThread.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SCThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public SCThread(Socket socket) {
        super("ServidorChatThread");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));) {
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < Usuarios.lista.size(); i++) {

                    if (inputLine.startsWith(i + " ")) {
                        Usuarios.lista.get(i).envia(this.getName() + " te diz: " + inputLine.substring(2));
                    }
                }

                if (inputLine.startsWith("x ")) {

                    for (SCThread usuario : Usuarios.lista) {

                        if (usuario != this) {
                            usuario.envia(this.getName() + ": " + inputLine.substring(2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void envia(String msg) throws IOException {
        socket.getOutputStream().write((msg + "\n").getBytes());

    }

}
```

ChatCliente.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatCliente {

    static Socket s;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Utilizacao: java ChatCliente <endereco> <porta>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        s = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

        ClienteThread cT = new ClienteThread(s);
        cT.start();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

            enviar(scan.nextLine() + "\n");

        }
        scan.close();

    }

    public static void enviar(String str) throws IOException {

        s.getOutputStream().write(str.getBytes());

    }
}
```

ClienteThread.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteThread extends Thread {

    BufferedReader in;

    public ClienteThread(Socket s) throws IOException {

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    }

    String mensagem;

    public void run() {

        try {
            while ((mensagem = in.readLine()) != null)

                System.out.println(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Usuarios.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Usuarios {

    public static ArrayList<SCThread> lista = new ArrayList<SCThread>();

    public static void adicionar(SCThread u) throws IOException {

        lista.add(u);
        u.setName("Usuario " + (lista.size() - 1));
        u.envia("Servidor: Voce eh o " + u.getName());
        System.out.println("Quantidade de usuarios: " + lista.size());
    }

}
```

Note que isso é só uma idéia geral. Muitas etapas foram deixadas de lado, e muitas coisas precisam ser implementadas. Por exemplo:

1. Esse código não é thread safe (se muitos usuários conectarem ao mesmo tempo, ele vai travar). Mais notável é o `ArrayList<>` que deve ser substituído, como dito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716016/1579771).
2. Não existe tratamente para quebra de conexão - se um usuário desconectar, ele vai começar a dar erro também (eu removi para reduzir o tamanho do código).