# Como só enviar mensagens para os outros clientes?

Tags: java, socket

Tenho uma dúvida com sockets java. Meu código envia as mensagens para todos os clientes, inclusive o que envia. Quero que ele envie apenas para os outros clientes. Tem como fazer isso? Eu testo usando o comando `telnet 127.0.0.1 2015` no terminal.

Cliente

```
package socket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Clientes implements Runnable {

    public Socket cliente;

    public Clientes(Socket cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.write("---Seja Bem Vindo---\n");
            out.flush();

            System.out.println("Nova conexao: "
                    + this.cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            while (true) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        cliente.getInputStream()));
                String veioDoCliente = in.readLine();

                if(veioDoCliente.equalsIgnoreCase("SAIR")){
                    cliente.close();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("MSG vinda do cliente " + veioDoCliente);

                for (Clientes writer : Servidor.clientes) {
                    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(writer.cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out2.write("teste:"+veioDoCliente+"\n");
                    out2.flush();

                }


                //s.close();
                 //this.cliente.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Servidor

```
package socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Servidor {
    public Socket cliente;

    public Servidor(Socket cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }


    public static List<Clientes> clientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(2015);

        System.out.println("Esperando alguem se conectar...");

        while (true) {
            Socket cliente = servidor.accept();

            Clientes tratamento = new Clientes(cliente);

            clientes.add(tratamento);

            Thread t = new Thread(tratamento);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você envia as mensagens neste código:

```
for (Clientes writer : Servidor.clientes) {
    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(writer.cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
    out2.write("teste:"+veioDoCliente+"\n");
    out2.flush();
}
```

Para cada instância de `Clientes` (chamada `writer`), você envia a mensagem gerada na instância atual (que é uma instância de `Clientes`) - logo, é possível comparar `writer` com a instância atual:

```
if (writer != this) {
    // ... código exposto acima
}
```

*"Se `writer` não for eu mesma, envie a mensagem."*

Eu respondi uma pergunta, incluindo um exemplo que continha exatamente o que você está fazendo aqui. Sugiro que você dê uma olhada - [pode te servir para alguma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78465/4816).

> Sugestão:
>
> Neste *loop*, use `cliente` ao invés de `writer`, e na hora de instanciar o `Socket` na classe `Servidor`, o chame também de `socket`.

Assim quando você escrever:

```
new PrintWriter(writer.cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Ficará assim:

```
new PrintWriter(cliente.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Que acredito ser mais fácil de entender.